# SQL Server Special Characters Sort By

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unicode, special-characters, encode

I want to sort using SQL_Romanian_CP1250_CS_AS and as a result I get:

```
Du
Șe
Ge
```

Which should be

```
Du
Ge
Șe
```

I think that it ignores the special character and I don't know why.

I try different Fonts, Encoding, Collates and even some of the Locale/Language Pack unicode like if I try to insert in without an N in front of string like "Șe" instead of N"Șe" I get "?e", but if I try "ă" it is inserted correctly. As I enter manually the row, it is inserted corrected.

Comment: `SQL_Romanian_CP1250_CS_AS` is a legacy collation (i.e. no-one should be using it for new projects) - do you have a good reason for wanting to use it instead of the more modern `Romanian_100_CS_AS` or `Romanian_100_CS_AS_WS_SC` or even `Romanian_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC_UTF8`?

Comment: Is your text stored in a `varchar` or `nvarchar` column? Are you opted-in to using SQL Sever's UTF-8 or UTF-16-Supplementary-Chars support?

Comment: @Dai I tried with Romanian_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC_UTF8 and it worked. I use nvarchar.

Comment: _if I try to insert in without an N in front of string like "Șe" instead of N"Șe" I get "?e"_ Character literals (as opposed to National character literals with the `N` prefix) are subject to the database's default collation, so what's the database's default collation? i.e.: what's the output of `SELECT [name], collation_name FROM sys.databases WHERE [name]=DB_NAME();`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Actally, after changing collation it works even without N prefix.

Comment: The  `Ș` (U+0218,  *Latin Capital Letter S With Comma Below*) isn't present in `cp1250`; it's 2024: switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/).